# Should I use username or Facebook Id?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

In my ASP.NET MVC app, I'm using Facebook authentication and I was using numeric Facebook Id's to see if a user is already in my system -- not the username but the id.

However, today I came across an interesting situation. I seem to have 2 Facebook Id's myself even though I only have one Facebook account and both ID's are pointing to the same Facebook username.

Not sure why Facebook returns different Id's for me. After this interesting discovery, I started to question the validity of my approach. Should I use Facebook usernames to check if a user is already registered in my system as opposed to the numeric Id?

Comment: 2 IDs for a single Facebook account? That doesn't sound right. How did you find out you had 2 IDs?

Comment: I knew my original Facebook Id and had stored it in my database. I found this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading

Looks like Facebook now creates a new ID for each user based on app. They call it app scoped Id.

Comment: If you're using `Facebook's Graph API`, you can check your ID at https://graph.facebook.com/YourUserName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your stored you old "global" user_id, and the new app-scoped one. You can't use the `username` field in v2.0 anymore, because it's deprecated. Why don't you use the `third_party_id`? This is meant to fulfill your purpose.

Comment: I think you're right. third_party_id seems to be the right approach. For those who have multiple apps, Facebook offers Business Mapping API so that different app scoped Id's from different apps can be mapped for the same user. Thank you for your help.